# Extracting JSON from API response using .json() causes entire Django view to run multiple times

Tags: json, django, python-requests

On a locally-hosted Django server, I'm using the `requests` module to send an request to an external API. For example, this code works fine:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

import requests

url = "https://rapidapi.com"
apiKey = "MY-KEY"
apiHost = "isitwater-com.p.rapidapi.com"
headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": apiKey,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": apiHost
}
locationParameters = {
    "latitude": "32",
    "longitude": "-26"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=locationParameters)
print(response)

def generatePage(request):
    return HttpResponse()
```

And outputs what I'd expect:

```
<Response [200]>
```

But when I try to get the JSON from the (supposedly) successful request using `.json()`, the entire view runs twice and then throws an error. For example, this code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

import requests

url = "https://rapidapi.com"
apiKey = "MY-KEY"
apiHost = "isitwater-com.p.rapidapi.com"
headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": apiKey,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": apiHost
}
locationParameters = {
    "latitude": "32",
    "longitude": "-26"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=locationParameters)
print(response)
print(response.json())

def generatePage(request):
    return HttpResponse()
```

Outputs the following:

```
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Derek\Desktop\World Color Map\World_Color_Map-xFfPFma1\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Derek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Derek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Derek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I know this error means that `.json()` isn't outputting valid JSON, despite the status code 200. But not only that, `<Response [200]>` was printed twice. Is there a way to fix this problem or get the JSON some other way?

Comment: But how do you run that? Why you have code outside function in django views?